# How to Add and Remove specific columns from Grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to remove a specific column/row when the window `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` is over 700. I couldn't really find a way to remove a specific column/row besides

```
myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.RemoveAt(1);
```

which removes one column everytime the widow size changes.

Current Grid:

```
<Grid x:Name="myGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition MaxHeight="80" MinHeight="80"/>
        <RowDefinition MaxHeight="80" MinHeight="80"/>
        <RowDefinition MaxHeight="80" MinHeight="80"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
        <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="170" MinWidth="170" x:Name="ColumnThatNeedsToBeRemovedAndReadded"/>
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="110" Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="350" MaxWidth="700"/>
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="170" Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Code which Adds/Removes:

```
 if (ActualHeight > 700 && ActualWidth > 700)
 {
    myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.RemoveAt(1);
 }
 else if(ActualHeight < 700 && ActualWidth > 700)
 {
    myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
 }
```

Comment: What's wrong with `myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.RemoveAt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to remove a specific column:

```
   for (var index = 0; index < myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count; index++)
    {
        var currentCol = myGrid.ColumnDefinitions[index];
        if (currentCol.ActualWidth > 700)
        {
            myGrid.Children.RemoveAt(index);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works with .Name = "your column" instead of ActualWidth. Thanks